# Is this sentence correct in terms of collocation?

Tags: word-usage, collocations

Is the collocation of "irritable questioning manner"correct? Also, is the phrase "young enthusiastic man" common?

> Ryan peered at Jake with an **irritable questioning manner** that was to be expected from a **young enthusiastic man** like him.

Comment: What prompts you to ask?  Does it look unusual?

Comment: It does look unusual because I think irritable is a kind of adjective we normally use for fixed qualities about people, not about trivial things. Also, I doubt about "questioning manner". I've written the sentence myself, so I think It might fairly be wrong to use these collocations.

Comment: I think the transference of "irritable" quality from the man who exhibits it to the manner of that man is short and safe.  Akin to the step from "low temperature" to "cold temperature".